# problemas al conectar putty a un vps ssh

Tags: ssh, vps, putty

Tengo un vps el cual no puedo ingresar mediante putty con ssh,

Éstas son las configuraciones del ssh:

```
.# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
.# sshd_config(5) for more information.

.# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

.# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
.# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
.# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
.# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

.#Port 22
.#AddressFamily any
.#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
.#ListenAddress ::

.#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
.#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
.#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

.# Ciphers and keying
.#RekeyLimit default none

.# Logging
.#SyslogFacility AUTH
.#LogLevel INFO

.# Authentication:

LoginGraceTime 1m
PermitRootLogin no
.#StrictModes yes
.#MaxAuthTries 6
.#MaxSessions 10


.#PubkeyAuthentication yes

.# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
.#AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

.#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

.#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
.#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

.# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
.#HostbasedAuthentication no
.# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
.# HostbasedAuthentication
.#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
.# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
.#IgnoreRhosts yes

.# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
.#PasswordAuthentication yes
.#PermitEmptyPasswords no

.# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
.# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

.# Kerberos options
.#KerberosAuthentication no
.#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
.#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
.#KerberosGetAFSToken no

.# GSSAPI options
.#GSSAPIAuthentication no
.#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
.#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
.#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

.# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
.# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
.# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
.# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
.# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
.# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
.# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
.# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
.# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

.#AllowAgentForwarding yes
.#AllowTcpForwarding yes
.#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
.#X11DisplayOffset 10
.#X11UseLocalhost yes
.#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
.#PrintLastLog yes
.#TCPKeepAlive yes
.#PermitUserEnvironment no
.#Compression delayed
.#ClientAliveInterval 0
.#ClientAliveCountMax 3
.#UseDNS no
.#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
MaxStartups 10:30:100
.#PermitTunnel no
.#ChrootDirectory none
.#VersionAddendum none

.# no default banner path
.#Banner none
DebianBanner no

.# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

.# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

.# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
.#Match User anoncvs
.#  X11Forwarding no
.#  AllowTcpForwarding no
.#  PermitTTY no
.#  ForceCommand cvs server
PasswordAuthentication yes
UseDNS no
 
.# Hestia SFTP Chroot
Match User sftp_dummy99,admin11,jose11
    ChrootDirectory %h
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTCPForwarding no
.#    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: consulta, podrías adjuntar el error te que lanza?, gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: incluye cómo te estás intentando conectar.